# Supporting pubescent daughter's curiousity about "normal bodies"

Tags: middle-childhood, sexual-development

Along with others in her peer group she has begun developing breasts and today asked if she could see her grandmother's breasts to contrast them to her mother's. This seems like quite normal curiosity which would be good to fulfill with an understanding of the diversity of human body shapes (anticipating that her curiosity will extend to genetalia and beyond), rather having her impressions developed solely from the fashion/marketing/pornographic depictions of "ideal" body types.

Our initial notion is giving her a resource (illustrated book, DVD, website) which shows in some detail a range of normal bodies, both clothed and naked, not too anatomical. We would like suggestions, both about the approach and any specific materials/titles for it.

Note: she has seen generalized depictions of puberty (the venerable "What's Happening to Me?" book), has fairly routinely seen her parents naked, and doesn't seem to be worried about her body. She's 10 years old ("middle school", although in Germany that already puts her into the high-school equivalent, so she's a "small fish in the big pond")

Comment: I don't have time to formulate an appropriate answer but would certain explore the work of some photographers with "normal" people and un-retouched pictures. I would also seize the occasion to show her some examples of post-production work on pictures (aka photoshop) to emphasize that even the models are actually "normal" and perfection doesn't really exist in nature.

Comment: Picking up @LaurentS. comment here: IIRC, Brigitte (the German magazine) should have a few articles on the website, depicting “lots of ordinary people’s bodies / body parts”. (So she could also read the article describing the photographers’ work.)

Comment: @LaurentS. and perhaps a few “photoshop fails”  - there are enough wannabe-celebrities supplying that kind of material ;-)

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments so far: I do indeed have a small stock of photoshop absurdities to try to defuse insecurities.Any war stories of what you've tried with your children and how that panned out?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find appropriate photos online of non-sexual adult nudity by looking for photos of naturist/nudist (in germany FKK).

You can search Getty Images for “naturist photography”, seek out work by portrait photographers like Laura Pannack, look at media coverage of nude protests like the World Naked Bike Ride, or even educational programmes which feature full frontal nudity like the british Sex Education Show.

Sadly the internet being what it is, these searches will undoubtedly bring up pornography mixed in with the genuine content, so seek it out on your own first, then share what’s appropriate with your daughter.

In terms of a resource that specifically focusses on bodies throughout puberty, there is a Norwiegen show called Pubertet which is probably close to what you describe.

Comment: A Celebration of the Breast, is such a project

Answer (score 0):

I think we all understand the curiousity. But I feel like it might serve her better to understand that even though we are all fundamentally the same, we are also different. Each of us is beautiful in our own way. You can not compare what makes her beautiful with what makes the next person beautiful. It is our individuality, not necessarily our physical self.